# Slow schema / table creation in postgres

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant, postgresql-9.5

I have a postgres database with ~65,000 schemas (one-per-customer), each with ~5 - 20 tables.  I'm noticing that creating new schemas and tables seems to be slowing down.  I'm guessing there might be a system table that's not indexed properly to support this scenario, but calling "EXPLAIN CREATE SCHEMA" throws a syntax error, so I'm at a loss for how to debug this.  Any ideas?

EDIT: This is an Amazon RDS database, m4.2xlarge instance w/ high availability, 400 GB of SSD storage.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you took special steps, you're storing 325,000 to 1.3 million files in a single directory. Not all filesystems deal gracefully with that many files one directory.

The *special steps* involve [creating tablespaces](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html), and [moving tables or indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html) using `alter table ... set tablespace ...`.

Comment: What about creating more than one database to hold that many schemas?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : By default, new database files will go in the same directory. I think you need tablespaces.

Comment: If the problem is indeed the directory. Maybe you could extend the answer to recommend multiple databases in multiple tablespaces.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I didn't recommend multiple databases. OP has an existing multi-tenant system that includes 65k schemas and tables in *one* database. Changing to multiple databases would *probably* require rewriting a fair amount of application code. Changing to multiple tablespaces doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Will do some investigation to see if that's what's going on (I'm on RDS right now, so might be hard to mess with the filesystem, we'll see...)

Comment: @josh: RDS changes things. You should edit your question, and include information about RDS. (Storage type and DB Instance Metrics)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' thanks, editing the question to include that info